# BLE scanning issue in SAMSUNG

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I am sacnning BLE device in SAMSUNG device s4(lolipop) and GT(kitkat), It is taking too much time more than other device. It is contiously scaning BLE devices even already scan. My logs:

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=6A:40:8C:39:DF:DD RSSI=-92
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=6A:40:8C:39:DF:DD RSSI=-86
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=00:07:80:C7:BD:16 RSSI=-61
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=6A:40:8C:39:DF:DD RSSI=-88
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=C2:0C:78:26:03:B2 RSSI=-90
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=00:07:80:C7:BD:16 RSSI=-61
D/BluetoothAdapter: onScanResult() - Device=6A:40:8C:39:DF:DD RSSI=-88
```

I am getting this log continous around 1 minutes. Due to continuous logs, I am unable to connect BLE device.

Comment: Post your code that you use to connect to BLE.

Comment: That is normal behaviour for some devices. I doubt this is the reason you can not connect